# QTableView check if the String already exists

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, model-view, qabstracttablemodel

I have a Program which puts Strings into a TableView with Model/View.
My model extrends from QAbstractTableModel and my view from QTableView.
It is sorting by the Name in my model `setData()`:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), names.size(), names.size());
names.push_back(name);
values.push_back(value);
endInsertRows();
```

Now i would check if the String i would add, already exists in my table, when it exists i wouldn't add it. 
With a `QTableWidget` can i make `it` so :

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> ItemList = table->findItems(strname, Qt::MatchExactly);
if ( ItemList.count() == false )
{/*add*/}
else {/*QMessageBox */}
```

But with a QTableView i don't know.
what should i do ?

Then i always have checkboxes in my Table but i never added they . 
When i add 1, it make the checkboxes automatically blue.

Here is a link to the methode , that works very strange : [View::PushButtonClicked](http://pastebin.com/3uieTWPh)

Comment: Now my Programm do very strange thinks.
When i add  " 1 " & " 1 " 
Than i add  " 1 " & " 1 " and push in my msgBox " Save" it saves, but 
than i add " Hallo " " Du " .
It says that it already exists and than
it clears the table for example.

[Here is the methode][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/3uieTWPh

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a subclass of QAbstractItemModel (or QAbstractTableModel) from which you get the data.
You can check the String searching in your model calling your implementation of

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
```

or you can searching in the source from which this member return a QVariant;

or you can use

```
QModelIndexList QAbstractItemModel::match ( const QModelIndex & start, int role, const QVariant & value, int hits = 1, Qt::MatchFlags flags = Qt::MatchFlags( Qt::MatchStartsWith | Qt::MatchWrap ) ) const
```

Answer (score 0):

For table view, you can search its model for the given text with using `QAbstractItemModel::match()` function. For example:

```
QModelIndexList indexes = model->match(QModelIndex(), Qt::DisplayRole, "text");
if (indexes.size() > 0) {
    // Add new item...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search in your model using [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSortFilterProxyModel.html#details) :

```
QSortFilterProxyModel proxy;
proxy.setSourceModel(myTableModel);
proxy.setFilterFixedString(searchString);

QModelIndex matchingIndex = proxy.mapToSource(proxy.index(0,0))

 if(matchingIndex.isValid())
 {
     QMessageBox::information(this, "Find", "Found");
 }
 else
 {
     QMessageBox::information(this, "Find", "Not Found");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
But i have 2 Strings : Name & Value.
But I only will check if the name exists, not the same String as value. 
And when i close the msgBox, the table is cleared o.o ?!
For example i add Name : AName , Value: AValue.
Than i add :  Name:AValue, Value: BValue. that should be add. but it says that the String exists ..